# Generate entities and database tables from YAML schema file

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony6

I'm using Symfony 6 with latest Doctrine.

Is there a way to generate Doctrine entities (and ideally the corresponding database tables) directly from a YAML schema file? This could be a single YAML file or multiple entity-specific files.

Unless I'm missing something, it seems I'm forced to generate an entities using the Symfony console, entity-by-entity, field-by-field, which is very cumbersome.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Nothing that I know of.  You can generate entities from an existing database schema.  Or at least make a first shot at it.  Copy/pasting existing entities works surprisingly well. If you really felt you need this capability then cloning the existing make:entity command and convincing it to use a yaml file as input would probably not be difficult.  Of course you would still need to create the yaml file.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks. I'm arriving at a similar conclusion. Looking at converting my YAML file into DBAL schema syntax $table->addColumn() programmatically just now.